# How to use for loop to populate items in combo box using Visual Basic

Tags: vba

I need a for loop to populate consecutive values 18 - 100 in a combo box using visual basic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What Combobox are you talking about ?
Perhaps this can help you ?

```
Const SEP As String = ","
Dim iIndex As Integer
Dim sList As String

sList = 18
For iIndex = 19 To 100
    sList = sList & SEP & iIndex
Next

Call Excel.ActiveCell.Validation.Add( _
    Type:=Excel.XlDVType.xlValidateList, _
    Formula1:=sList)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
dim n as integer
dim new as variable

for n=18 to 100
  new.additem n
next n
```

Comment: Um, "variable" is not a valid built-in VBA type, and `Variant`s don't come as collections unless you set them to. This won't compile.